# ClearCase, Mapping specific folders into Drives, using dynamic views

Tags: clearcase

I need to map a directory into it's own drive, (i know it's achivable using windows tools like "Map network drive", "subst"), but using these tools, the mapped drives aren't MVFS anymore...

I'm looking for a way to map MVFS folders in some dynamic view to it's own drive, or alternativly, configure a config spec to filter everything except a specific folder, for example, configure a config spec so that:

M:\some_dynamic_view\some_folder\some_nested_folder
would be mapped to :

K:\some_nested_folder

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Erik.

(The need to map folders into drives is because of the clearcase path length limitation on windows).

Answer (score 0):

I just tested:

```
 subst N: M:\some_dynamic_view\some_folder\some_nested_folder
```

and N: would display the content of `some_nested_folder`, as a dynamic view would.
Its type is a MVFS filesystem drive (named `CCase` by default)

Now, to have only the directory (and not directly its content) in N:\, you would need a config spec like:

```
element /some_folder/some_nested_folder/... /main/LATEST
element /some_folder/* -none
element * /main/LATEST
```

(supposing a simple non-UCM view, with only the main branch to see. Adapt the config spec to your configuration and branch on which you need to read/modify files.
For a UCM view, that would be trickier, since those rules would have to be place *before* all the other generated UCM selection rules, meaning they would disappear at the next view config spec synchronization with its stream.)
(note: no need to use '`\`' in config spec, '`/`' works just fine, for Windows or Unix config spec)

Then, a:

```
subst N: M:\some_dynamic_view\some_folder
```

would only display `some_nested_folder` (and its content) in N:

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, i'll try changing the config spec... :))

Answer (score 0):

I mainly use snapshot views so I don't think I can use the m:\path_to_view solution. After many years of shouting "doh" at my monitor I wrote this batch file to save me having to change directory back to the original location of the view every time I wanted to run a cleartool command.

```
@echo off
rem ct.bat by Paul Douglas
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set currentDirectory=%cd:~2,8189%
set currentDrive=%cd:~0,1%

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('subst') do (
set thisDrive=%%a
set thisDrive=!thisDrive:~0,1!
set targetFolder=%%a
set targetFolder=!targetFolder:~8,8183!
if "!thisDrive!"=="%currentDrive%" (
  pushd !targetFolder!%currentDirectory% 
  call cleartool %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 
  popd 
  goto :eof
)
)

call cleartool %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```