# Mounting Drives and launching Apps With PowerShell

Tags: powershell, clearcase

I am trying to unmount a drive, mount the drive, start a view, mount vobs then call a perl script.

The problem that I am running into is, it seems I have to run as administrator to mount drives but my program has to run as a specific user.
I can get the mount commands to run if I run the the powershell as an admin but I need to run the perl scipts as a user.

How do I get both parts to run as a user?

I have tried commented and uncommented versions

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\net.exe use Z: /d
#Remove-PSDrive Z
sleep 2

cleartool endview -server Bedrock_Main_mvwd01tc_1
sleep 2

##new-psdrive -name Z -psprovider FileSystem -root \\view\Bedrock_Main_mvwd01tc_1 
c:\WINDOWS\system32\net.exe use Z: \\view\Bedrock_Main_mvwd01tc_1
sleep 2


##%DRIVE% ##|| goto NETUSEERROR
Set-Location Z:\CMTools\buildtools
cd Z:\CMTools\buildtools

cleartool mount -a

### SET THE CONFIG SPEC TO THE NIGHTLY TIMESTAMP.
\\usmvwc0wafnsrv.ww005.siemens.net\EngTools\bin\chrcs -p $PROJECT -n -m -f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows,  all dynamic views are mounted automatically on `M:` drive, so you shouldn't need to use a non ClearCase command (net.exe) to start a view.

Simply [`cleartool startview aViewTag`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm) is enough.

If you need to use a drive letter for a specific view, start the view first (for dynamic view especially, otherwise it won't be visible under `M:\`), and then use `subst`.

See " [ClearCase, Mapping specific folders into Drives, using dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062810/clearcase-mapping-specific-folders-into-drives-using-dynamic-views/2062854#2062854) " for a concrete example.