# How to separate ClearCase view and VOB?

Tags: windows, clearcase

I got a mission to separate the view prefix and VOB path. i.e. get the VOB + file path for both dynamic and snapshot views on Windows.

e.g.
for all the following examples, I have to get this: `\vob\folders\...\filename`

Dynamic views:

- M:\view-tag\vob\folders...\filename
- T:\vob\folders...\filename

Snapshot views:

- C:\users\bob\documents\cc\view-tag\vob\folders...\filename
- \\hostname\shared-folder\view-tag\vob\folders...\filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply start anywhere in your view and type [cleartool pwv](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_pwv.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.2%2F8-0-0-1-48):

```
cleartool pwv -root
```

That using:

```
-root
```

> Returns the root directory path of the current working view.
>   **This root is the portion of an element's absolute path that precedes the VOB tag**.

Comment: Does it always work with dynamic views? If I cd to T:\vob and run 'cleartool pwv -root', it returns nothing

Comment: @user1762109 Only with dynamic view path starting with `M:\` (the official MVFS mount point). `T:\` is just a windows `subst`, a way to make the path shorter. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/2062854/6309.